# Highlighting the rows of a column while searching for multiple keywords

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, countif

I am trying to highlight the rows of a column based on multiple keywords from a list of cells. I did this using this formula in the Conditional Formatting -

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A6,"*"&Keywords&"*"))
```

where, `Keywords` is a row of 7 cells, where I can type in my keywords. However, if I leave any one of these cells empty, all of the rows of the column get highlight (because I assume '' matches with everything. So, I decided to pre-fill each of the empty cells in `Keywords` with `$$`.

In my opinion, this is just a work-around, and this can be handled better. Can anyone tell me how to handle this better, without pre-filling each cell of the keywords list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check for an empty cells in the keywords row:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$C$1:$I$1&"*")*NOT(ISBLANK($C$1:$I$1)))
```

[image]